# MongoIO Apache beam GCP Dataflow with Mongo Upsert Pipeline example

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, upsert, apache-beam-io

I am looking for an example to implement Apache beam GCP dataflow Pipeline to Update the data in Mongo DB using upsert operation i.e if the value exsit it should update the value and if not it should insert.

Syntax like below :

```
pipeline.apply(...)
.apply(MongoDbIO.write()
.withUri("mongodb://localhost:27017")
.withDatabase("my-database")
.withCollection("my-collection")
.withUpdateConfiguration(UpdateConfiguration.create().withUpdateKey("key1")
      .withUpdateFields(UpdateField.fieldUpdate("$set", "source-field1", "dest-field1"),
                        UpdateField.fieldUpdate("$set","source-field2", "dest-field2"),
                       //pushes entire input doc to the dest field
                         UpdateField.fullUpdate("$push", "dest-field3") )));
```

Below is my Pipeline Code where i am currently inserting the document after preapring the collection like below

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"619632693261e80017c44145"},"vin":"SATESTCAVA74621","timestamp":"2021-11-18T10:48:59.889Z","key":"EV_CHARGE_NOW_SETTING","value":"DEFAULT"}
```

Now i want to Update the '**value**' and '**timestamp**' if the combination of '**vin**' and '**key**' are present, if '**vin**' and '**key**' combination is not present then Insert the new document using upsert.

```
PCollection<PubsubMessage> pubsubMessagePCollection= pubsubMessagePCollectionMap.get(topic);
            pubsubMessagePCollection.apply("Convert pubsub to kv,k=vin", ParDo.of(new ConvertPubsubToKVFn()))
                .apply("group by vin key",GroupByKey.<String,String>create())
                .apply("filter data for alerts, status and vehicle data", ParDo.of(new filterMessages()))
                .apply("converting message to document type", ParDo.of(
                    new ConvertMessageToDocumentTypeFn(list_of_keys_str, collection, options.getMongoDBHostName(),options.getMongoDBDatabaseName())).withSideInputs(list_of_keys_str))
                .apply(MongoDbIO.write()
                    .withUri(options.getMongoDBHostName())
                    .withDatabase(options.getMongoDBDatabaseName())
                    .withCollection(collection));
```

Now if i want to use this below lines of code:

```
.withUpdateConfiguration(UpdateConfiguration.create().withUpdateKey("key1")
      .withUpdateFields(UpdateField.fieldUpdate("$set", "source-field1", "dest-field1"),
                        UpdateField.fieldUpdate("$set","source-field2", "dest-field2"),
                       //pushes entire input doc to the dest field
                         UpdateField.fullUpdate("$push", "dest-field3") )));
```

What will be my **key1**, **"source-field1", "dest-field1"**, **"source-field2", "dest-field2"**, **"dest-field3"** ?

I am confused with this values. Please help !

Below code i am trying to update

```
MongoDbIO.write()
.withUri(options.getMongoDBHostName())
.withDatabase(options.getMongoDBDatabaseName())
.withCollection(collection)
.withUpdateConfiguration(UpdateConfiguration.create()
                            .withIsUpsert(true)
                            .withUpdateKey("vin")
                            .withUpdateKey("key")
                            .withUpdateFields(UpdateField.fieldUpdate("$set", "vin", "vin"),
                                              UpdateField.fieldUpdate("$set", "key", "key"),
                                              UpdateField.fieldUpdate("$set", "timestamp", "timestamp"),
                                              UpdateField.fieldUpdate("$set", "value", "value")))
```

Using above code My document is not updating instead adding with id = vin , it should update based the exsiting record with vin and key match, also if insert it should insert with auto generated _id value.

Please suggest what to do here ?

Comment: I have two search key i.e **vin** and **key** how can i create this pipeline code ?

Answer (score 1):

upsert configuration is read from [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/mongodb/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/mongodb/MongoDbIO.java#L1007), you can configure it with [withIsUpsert](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/mongodb/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/mongodb/UpdateConfiguration.java#L79)(true).

In your original syntax, add the extra line to enable upsert.

```
pipeline.apply(...)
  .apply(MongoDbIO.write()
    .withUri("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    .withDatabase("my-database")
    .withCollection("my-collection")
    .withUpdateConfiguration(
      UpdateConfiguration.create()
        .withIsUpsert(true)
        .withUpdateKey("key1")
        .withUpdateFields(
          UpdateField.fieldUpdate("$set", "source-field1", "dest-field1"),
          UpdateField.fieldUpdate("$set","source-field2", "dest-field2"),
          //pushes entire input doc to the dest field
          UpdateField.fullUpdate("$push", "dest-field3"))));
```

Comment: Can i have the example which can show how in Apache beam Dataflow I can user this MongDBIO Upsert.

Comment: You just need the extra update configuration. If you need a whole executable example such as a jupyter notebook, I don't really have one.

Comment: Hi @ningk, I have updated my actual query with more specific details. If you could help me with this. Much Appreciated. Thanks !